# Arduino not taking multiple commands

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to get the basics done with my Arduino, and thus I'm starting off small.

That said, I want the Arduino to listen for simple, multiple commands being sent from my Raspberry Pi (I'm emulating this through the serial monitor now, however)

This is the code I'm working with:

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.find("test1")) {
      delay(100);
      Serial.println("TEST1 command received");
    }
    if (Serial.find("test2")) {
      delay(100);
      Serial.println("TEST2 command received");
    }
  }
}
```

Sadly, only the test1 command triggers a serial print response, test2 no. Can anyone here help point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: `find` will block until `test1` is found or timed out, consuming all of the data on its way, including the `test2` strings that might be encountered. I suggest you to do a little research about the functions you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the documentation, I don't think you can use the [`find()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Find) function like that.

Consider what happens if `test2` is input, when the `find("test1")` call is running. It will probably consume all characters up to and including the `2`, and then return `false`, at which point those characters are lost.

I think you should design an actual protocol, with some delimiter between commands, and read/parse those.